# Model object and Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an object that I load up data from Core Data. I then modify the object with user inputs/choices.

My first though was to override the setter methods for the properties:

```
-(void)setType:(NSString *)type {
    NSLog(@"setType fired | newType: %@", type);

    _type = type;

    appDelegate *appDelegate = (appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:DEFAULTS_DB];

    NSError *error;

    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if (fetchedObjects.count == 1) {
        Defaults *defaults = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

        defaults.sceneType = type;
    }

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error in saving first run defaults | error: %@", error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"new type was saved to core data");
    }
}
```

My other thought was to update the Core Data when `applicationWillResignActive:` fires (but that method only gets a few seconds to run before the app is frozen) and when the user logs out.

The app i'm creating is one that the user would start up, set up what he wants, then puts it down 10-60min until he uses it again so i'm concerned with my app being killed while inactive and loosing the data.

Is updating core data in the setter method a good way to handle updates or is it a really bad idea (too resource intensive, too slow)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a typical usage pattern. Typical would be to fetch your object before displaying its data and hold it. Then when the user changes something, update object properties and save the context.

Answer (score 0):

It sort of depends on how much amount of data you are setting and retrieving with each call to your customer setters. I'd try what you are doing now (updating core data in setters) but test it out on an old device, say an iPad 1, and see how it performs. After playing it out for a while, you can decide whether you want to update core data with every setter or not.

Now, if you don't see any performance difference at all, I wouldn't worry about it. You're good. You are having the comfort of being able to save the most updated actions from the user by committing your data in setters. However, there might come a point when you are saving more data and/or large files/images and the earlier devices start to see a difference in performance.

In order to be prepared for such a situation in advance, I'd suggest having a buffer (that mirrors the structure of your entity) in your program that gets written to core data every so often - may be when the app goes into a state of inactivity or if the app goes into background or for every fixed time period. It's imperative the buffer gets updated in the setters. The possible hiccup with your idea of writing code in `applicationWillResignActive:` stems from how prepared you are at handling crashes. Crashes can happen any time for any reason, sometimes maybe not because of your own bad code. And this is one strong reason why having buffers is a good idea. You either lose one chunk of small data during a crash (worst case) or you achieve performance + consistency (best case).